# Why is ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone#to_f returning greater precision than what is stored in postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a Rails 5.2 application with a postgres backend. When I pull a timestamp from the database and convert it to a float (`to_f`), it should return the time in seconds with fractional seconds down to the microsecond (since the greatest precision postgres stores is microseconds). Instead, for about 25% of the timestamps I look at, I get 7 decimal digits (hundredths of nanoseconds) when converting timestamps to float.

```
irb(main):009:0> u.created_at.to_f
=> 1440127129.5120609
```

What's going on here? Shouldn't this be `1440127129.512060` or `1440127129.512061`? Where is this extra decimal digit coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Ruby's `inspect` as you see just prints out the value in the decimal form, converted from the internally stored form, which is a binary, and its representation has not much to do with its internal precision and absolutely nothing to do with the precision of the value stored in the database before it is imported to the Ruby object instance.

To demonstrate (a part of) the point, try `f=0.1000; p f` in irb or rails console. It just print "0.1" and *not* "0.1000".

Comment: Thanks! This drives me nuts but it makes sense.